# Token has expired and can no longer be refreshed

Tags: laravel, jwt, tymon-jwt

I'm using the package PHPOpenSourceSaver (Tymon package fork) and the access token is working perfect. When the time expires I update the access token and the user can continue access but when the refresh token expires I got the error:|

```
Token has expired and can no longer be refreshed
```

But I updated the refresh token (I think) in the middleware but it's not working, only update the access token when expires:

```
class JWTAuthenticate extends Authenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $jwt = $request->cookie(JWTValues::ACCESS_TOKEN);
        $bearerToken = null;
     
        if (!is_null($jwt)) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', $jwt);
        }

        try {
            JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {

            $refreshedToken =  auth()->refresh(JWTAuth::getToken());
            JWTAuth::setToken($refreshedToken)->toUser();

            $bearerToken = "Bearer {$refreshedToken}";
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', $bearerToken);
        }
     
        $this->authenticate($request);
       
        if (!is_null($bearerToken)) {
            $cookie = cookie()->forever(JWTValues::ACCESS_TOKEN, $bearerToken);
            return  $next($request)->withCookie($cookie);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I would like to know to thinks:

1. How to update the refresh token when this expires? the code in the middleware refresh the access token but with refresh token is the problem
2. is there a way to update the refresh token when the access token is updated?

Comment: You misunderstood something here, there is no "refresh token" and "access token", there is only one token. when the token expires, there is a delay during which you can generate a new token from the old one ("refreshed token or new token if you prefer) if you keep using the old token and that delay expires too, then you cant get a new token using the old one ans need to relog. to avoid it, when the token expires and you generate the new one, communicate it back to the client for him to use it from now on.

Comment: I would like that when I generate a new token the ttl_refresh start again and not continue with the old timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT package(s) have many security checks.

One of said checks, strictly forbids expired tokens to be refreshed (except maybe in a certain time-period after expired).

### Solutions

- Either refresh the token before it's expired, on each request.
- Or, as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76556704/token-has-expired-and-can-no-longer-be-refreshed/76556960#comment134980620_76556704) in comments, use JavaScript to refresh the token in the time-period that allows refreshing.
- Or, refresh the token with username and password.
- Or, hack the package, and remove/disable said "one" security check.

> **Note** that I only recommend first two of above, which is most secure.
>
> The remaining two allow a stolen token to be re-used by attackers, even if it's expired.
>
> But on the other hand, such a middle-man-attacker would steal user's name and password, too, and two-factor authentication with user's phone-number is required.

Comment: Bu when the TTL expires I can generate a new one and it's ok, the problem is when the ttl_refresh is expired, so Can I update the ttl_refresh for the new token and in this way extend the use.

Comment: @JuanPabloB Both TTL are or should be in time-out period format, a duration, not a real time that needs refreshing.

Comment: @JuanPabloB Also, if you refresh without JavaScript, no matter how much you increase TTL, there is no guarantee refresh happens in the right time-period.